# Issue reinstalling Unity

Tags: unity

A while ago I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 and played around with some themes. Now I have issues reinstalling Unity;

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then tried installing ubuntu-session and get this reply:

```
ubuntu-session : Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.14.0-2ubuntu4) but 3.14.0-2ubuntu5 is to be installed
```

Any thoughts on what to do? I am not sure if I should just force install the 2ubuntu4 version. Please note that I have to tried updating packages, cleaning cache etc.

Comment: try to run command `sudo apt-get install -f` . it will install broken packages.  then try to install  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`